# How to use multiple maps on single page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I want to use multipul map on single page.
Here is.

```
# example.html.erb
<%= gmaps4rails(@json1) %>
<%= gmaps4rails(@json2) %>
```

Map can't display, all map white out ...
Please help if anyone knows the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Since `v1.0.0`, it's really simple to add multiple maps on the same page, [see wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/%28Multiple%29-Maps).

---

It's not very straight as I didn't need this but it could be done quite easily.

```
first map here, it triggers the load of the necessary js files.
<%= gmaps4rails (@json1) %>

/the empty divs for second map (beware to provide the proper css)
<div id="second_container"> 
  <div id="second_map"></div>
</div>

<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script>

var counter = 0;

Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
  if (counter == 0){
    counter += 1;
    <%=   { "map_options" => {  
                          "container_id" => "second_container", "id" => "second_map",
                          "type" => "SATELLITE", "center_longitude" => 180, "zoom" => 3, "auto_adjust" => true 
                          },
            "markers"     => { "data" => @json2 }
          }.to_gmaps4rails(true).html_safe
    %>
   }
};
<script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

There has been some improvements to how this is done.

Now it is more like this:

```
<%= gmaps(:markers     => {:data => @json1 },
          :map_options => { :auto_adjust => true },
          :last_map    => false) %>
<%= gmaps(:markers     => @json2 },
          :map_options => { :id => "second_map", :center_on_user => true, :zoom => 5 },
          :scripts     => :none ) %>
```

Check out https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/%28Multiple%29-Maps

Comment: Oops. apneadiving beat me to mentioning this. Maybe my answer will help it be a bit more obvious.

Comment: OK!! Your answer is very nice!! Thx!!